# How to know that an object contains in a list ignoring case

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to compare an object, that if a list contains that object by ignoring case
Suppose take an example for this

```
Class A
{
    public string p1;
    public string p2;
}

Class B
{
    List<A> lst=new List<A>();
    A obj=new a();
    A obj1=new a();

    obj1.p1="ABCD";
    obj1.p2="xyz";

    obj.p1="abcd";
    obj.p2="XYZ";
    lst.add(obj1);

    lst.contains(obj)//return false
}
```

So I want to know how to compare it?

Comment: @Benesh - I know this but here list is not of type string. Its of type A(class)

Answer (score 4):

You can implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control how your objects are compared. You can then specify exactly how you want the comparison to work by implementing the Equals() method:

```
 public bool Equals(A other)
 {
     return this.P1.ToLower().Equals(other.P1.ToLower());
 }
```

Your

> lst.Contains(obj)

Should then work as you need.

Answer (score 0):

In class A override the Equals method to compare each of the properties ignoring case.

Then use:

```
bool found = lst.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(obj)) != null;
```

Comment: Simons solution seems better. Go for that one

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = lst.FirstOrDefault(c => c.p1 == obj.p1 && c.p2 == obj.p2);
if(result != null)
{
    //Your Code is here.
}
```